# Java string to xml to list

Tags: java, list, xml-parsing

I'm new to Java and need some help.
I have a XML that looks like:

```
String pXML =
"<root>
     <x>1</x>
     <x>2</x>
     <x>3</x>
     <x>4</x>
 </root>"
```

And I would like to get a List object that contains all of the values inside x tag.

I've tried with javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
document = (Document) builder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader(pXML) ) );
Node n = document.getFirstChild();
NodeList n1 = n.getChildNodes();
//and then I go through all the nodes and insert the values into a list
```

But this doesn't contain the x nodes.

Comment: I suspect the quote marks are causing the parser to skip all of the XML.

Comment: No, the pXML object I get as an input parametar, this is for you to understand what the xml looks like...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use XPath to get the values of all the `x` nodes as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {
    final String pXML = "<root><x>1</x><x>2</x><x>3</x><x>4</x></root>";
    final Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(pXML.getBytes()));
    final XPathExpression xPathExpression = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile("//x/text()");
    final NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPathExpression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    final List<String> values = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
        values.add(nodeList.item(i).getNodeValue());
    }
    System.out.println(values);
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This has the advantage of being a very general solution, easily adaptable if the structure of the XML changes.

It also has the advantage of being, in my opinion, much more understandable than iterating over the nodes in the `Document` by hand.

Comment: Agreed and using xPath is much less error prone. Iterating child nodes of an element may give you a blend a Text nodes and (sub) Elements that you would not necessarily expect.

Comment: Figured out what was the problem - in my code NodeValues in NodeList had non-trimmed values, so it had tons of values, from '\n' and ' '. Just a mess of chars and strings...

Answer (score 0):

Try `Node n = document.getDocumentElement();` to recover the root element of  your XML

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.CharacterData;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class XML {
  public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception{
    String xmlRecords = "<root><x>1</x><x>2</x><x>3</x><x>4</x></root>";

    DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlRecords));

    Document doc = db.parse(is);
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("x");
    System.out.println(nodes.getLength());
    List<String> valueList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
      Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);

      String name = element.getTextContent();

     // Element line = (Element) name.item(0);
      System.out.println("Name: " + name);
      valueList.add(name);
    }

  }
}
```